# Delta quaternion to euler adjustment

Tags: vector-spaces, quaternions

If I currently have two quaternions, $q_1$ and $q_2$, but I can only adjust in Euler values, how would you start to figure out what you need to add or subtract from the $x/y/z$ axis in order to obtain that rotation?

I'm currently trying $\Delta q = q_2 q_1^{-1}$ then taking $\Delta q$ into eulers. Finding the delta between that and the old euler, then making that adjustment, but it seems there is probably a better way.

Also, sorry I have no idea what the proper math symbols are for the code formulas above or I would have formatted them correctly :( Just a lowly programmer trying to figure his way through 3d math.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I've fixed the math markup for you; if you'd like something different, just say so. You can do this yourself using dollar signs.

Comment: For the conversion quaternion-Euler angles you can see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles